# React 16 wiith Node 18 issue: the callback was already called

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a React 17 project. We have upgraded recently on Node 16.20 LTS (after upgrading to Node 14 and then to Node 16).
We've juste upgraded to Node 18.20 LTS using "npm install" or "npm ci" with no specific problem.

But when we run project with "npm start" it fails with no more than "the callback was already called "

Can someone explain what is the problem ?

> typescript@1.0.0 start
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack/webpack.dev.js --mode development --open --hot

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9002/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from ....
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.9.7 from typescript
ℹ ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from /......./tsconfig.json
Error in bail mode: Error: callback(): The callback was already called.
    at context.callback (/home/...../node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:106:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) Error: callback(): The callback was already called.
    at context.callback (/......./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:106:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```